# CSS: Why isn't my content pushing down?

Tags: html, css

I've created a nice header for my site but when I try to add content after that such as a simple paragraph it's just getting placed in the same spot under my header container.  I've attempted some clear fixes but that did not solve my issue.  Thanks for your help in advance!

```css
   

#back-container {
 width: 1214px;
 height: 809px;
 background-image: url("coffee-beans 2.jpg");
}

#page-container {
 width: 900px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(214,214,214, .8);
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

header {
 width: auto;
 height: 130px;
 background-color: D8A071;
 border-bottom: 3px solid 864C1B;
 position: fixed;
 font-family: "Trattatello";
}

#logo {
 margin-top: -75px;
}

nav {
 float: right;
 width:  550px;
 padding-top: 40px;
}

nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 2px solid black;;
 background-color: 864C1B;
 padding-top: 15px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
 height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>New Coffee Site</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="coffeestyles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "back-container"> 
    <div id = "page-container">
 <header>    
   <img id = "logo" src = "coffelogo1.png">
            <nav>
    <a href="home.html"> Home </a>
    <a href="menu.html"> Menu </a>
    <a href="about.html"> About us </a>
    <a href="something.html"> Something </a>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <article>
   <p>
    asdfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf
   </p>
  </article>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header is fixed and so anything after it in the `HTML` will flow beneath it. Move the `<header>` to be outside of the `.page-container` and add margin to the top of the `.page-container` that is equal to the height of your header. This will push the content down so that it starts at the same point as your header ends.

You also need to add where your header will be with `top:0;` and `width:100%;`.

Here is a fiddle showing the changes I mae: http://jsfiddle.net/87c9wduf/

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the position: fixed. Add margin-top to the element you are using as a container that will move everything down.

Comment: @Sam Willis that's a good point; setting top: 0 sometimes it goes somewhere else when the fixed or absolute positioning is used!